# Add current date as value to a tag in ISO 8601 format XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="user">1234</entry>
</properties>
```

I want to add two new tags one contain the value of current date in ISO 8601 format and another one with the date set to current date + 10 years in ISO 8601 format and transform it into a new xml file using xslt, the output xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="user">1234</entry>
<entry key="doc:uploadDate">2017-07-04T22:18:08Z</entry>
<entry key="doc:deleteDate">2027-07-04T22:18:08Z</entry>
</properties>
```

I am using the below xslt.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="currentDate">
        <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="entry[@key='doc:uploadDate']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:value-of
                select="replace(normalize-space($currentDate),
        '^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})\s+(.*)','$3-$1-$2T$4Z')" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   
</xsl:transform>
```

Could someone please help me with this..

Comment: You have code there which appears to be converting a MM-DD-YYYY date into YYYY-MM-DD format, but the date comes from fn:current-dateTime, which is already YYYY-MM-DD format. Except that it actually comes back as an xs:dateTime, which you are turning into a string using xsl:value-of, and then parsing. Why all this complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a duration of ten years to the current date:

```
    <xsl:variable name="curr-date" select="current-dateTime()"/>
    <entry>
        <xsl:value-of select="$curr-date"/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <xsl:value-of select="$curr-date + xs:yearMonthDuration('P10Y')"/>
    </entry>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Martin. After using the above code I am getting the output date value as this **2017-07-04T15:19:42.959+05:30** but I want it to be like this **2017-07-04T15:19:42Z**. Please suggest.

Comment: You can use `format-dateTime` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-dateTime to create the desired format, take your time to look at the definition of the possible picture strings that function takes.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have used the below function and it is working pretty fine.
`<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[h01]:[m01]:[s01]Z')"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/properties">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <entry key="doc:uploadDate">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>
        </entry>
        <entry key="doc:deleteDate">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime() + xs:yearMonthDuration('P10Y')"/>
        </entry>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```